# Region is not getting selected in react-google-charts geo-chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I am trying to highlight the selected region in basic geochart using react-google-charts.

Here's how I want to do it [jsfiddle](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/RakanNimer/react-google-charts/tree/master/sandboxes/geo-chart/default?from-embed=&file=/App.tsx:80-261).

As you can see in above example when the region is clicked it keeps highlighted till next one is clicked. I have used the same example in my code and it is not working. It does not keep the region highlighted after click.

Here is my code sample,( same as the jsfiddle example )

```
import Chart from "react-google-charts";

const test = [
        ["Country", "Popularity"],
        ["Germany", 200],
        ["United States", 300],
        ["Brazil", 400],
        ["Canada", 500],
        ["France", 600],
        ["RU", 700],
        ["India", 900]
    ];


render(){
    return(
        <div>
           <Chart
             chartEvents={[
            {
                eventName: "select",
                callback: ({ chartWrapper }) => {
                const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
                const selection = chart.getSelection();
                if (selection.length === 0) return;
                const region = test[selection[0].row + 1];
                console.log("Selected : " + region);
                },
            },
            ]}
            chartType="GeoChart"
            width="100%"
            height="400px"
            data={test}
          />
       </div>
    )  
}
```

I don't know where I am going wrong. I am using react with javascript. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: will you please share the code that doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, I have edited the question please check